# Showing that $f(U) \subset W$ is a subspace and that $f^{-1}(X)$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $U \subset V$ and $X \subset W$ be subspaces. Let $f: V\to W$ be a linear transformation. Show that $f(U) \subset W$ is a subspace and that $f^{-1}(X)$ is a subspace.

In order to show that $f(U)$ is a subspace I have to show that the zero vector is in $f(U)$ and that it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication or that any linear combination of two elements in $f(U)$ is also in $f(U)$?

Let $w_1,w_2 \in f(U)$ and $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Now since $w_1,w_2 \in f(U)$ there exists $u_1$ and $u_2$ $\in U$ such that $f(u_1)=w_1$ and $f(u_2) = w_2$. Considering $c_1w_1+c_2w_2$ I have that $$c_1w_1+c_2w_2=c_1f(u_1)+c_2f(u_2)= f(c_1u_1+c_2u_2) \in f(U)$$

and so $f(U)$ would be a subspace?

For the second part I couldn't came up with much... how should I get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your proof is absolutely correct. The second part is quite similar. Let $a,b\in f^{-1}(X),$ which is to say that $f(a)\in X$ and $f(b) \in X$. Consider $c_1 a + c_2 b$. Is $f(c_1 a + c_2 b)\in X$? Well, this is just $c_1 f(a) +c_2 f(b)$, which is a linear combination of two elements of $X$. Since $X$ is a subspace, it is true that $c_1 f(a) +c_2 f(b)\in X$, which shows that $f^{-1} (X)$ is closed under linear combinations.
You are right that for both parts, you also need to argue that $0$ is part of the subset in question. This part shouldn't be too hard.